# simultaneously run different thread without waiting for other thread to complete

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

The thing is i want to use c++ library which runs different threads simultaneously without having other threads to wait until the preceding thread is complete and their functionality within each thread is run simultaneuslly,I am talking about the code which is to be run in the thread;the sample code is shown below.

```
   while(condition is true<it is infinite loop >){
   running sleep here with random time
     sleep(random time(sec))
     rest of the code is here
   }
```

This infinite `while` loop is run in each thread. I want to run this while loop in each thread to be run simultaneously without being stuck at the first thread to be completed. In other words all the infinite while loop(in each thread context) is to be run simultaneously. How do I achieve that? If you can please share some sample code actually I have used future with async but I get the same behavior as normal `<thread>` using `join()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is because of the rather silly definition of `std::async` (in my opinion) that it doesn't have to execute your code asynchronously, but can instead run it when you attempt to get from its `std::future` return value.

No matter. If you set the first parameter of your call to `std::launch::async` you force it to run asynchronously. You can then save the future in a container, and if you retire futures from this container regularly, you can run as many threads as the system will let you.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using future_store = std::vector<std::future<void>>;

void retireCompletedThreads(future_store &threadList)
{
    for (auto i = threadList.begin(); i != threadList.end(); /* ++i */)
    {
        if (i->wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready)
        {
            i->get();
            i = threadList.erase(i);
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

void waitForAllThreads(future_store &threadList)
{
    for (auto& f : threadList)
    {
        f.get();
    }
}

std::mutex coutMutex;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    future_store threadList;

    // No infinite loop here, but you can if you want.
    // You do need to limit the number of threads you create in some way though,
    // for example, only create new threads if threadList.size() < 20.
    for (auto i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        auto f = std::async(std::launch::async,
                [i]() {
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(coutMutex);
                    std::cout << "Thread " << i << " started" << std::endl;
                }
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(coutMutex);
                    std::cout << "Thread " << i << " completed" << std::endl;
                }
                });
        threadList.push_back(std::move(f));

        // Existing threads need to be checked for completion every so often
        retireCompletedThreads(threadList);
    }
    waitForAllThreads(threadList);
}
```